# laravel 7 ffmpeg encoding failed

Tags: ffmpeg, laravel-7

am Saving in default public directory but it is not working. Write Permission is also given to public directory.

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('user_public')
    ->open('big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4')
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('user_public')
     ->addWatermark(function(WatermarkFactory $watermark) {
        $watermark->fromDisk('user_public')
            ->open('logo.png')
            ->right(25)
            ->bottom(25);
    })
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
    ->save('big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb_new.mp4');
```

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 7.x

we i replace this line

```
->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
```

to

```
->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac'))
```

then worked fine for me.